# Is there a built in function to find the operating system?

Tags: imagej, fiji

So I want to navigate the file system from within a Fiji script, and create files. macOS uses `/` as a separator while windows uses `\` as a file separator. I can't for the life of me find an easy way to do this given the poor search ability of the documentation.

For example, in Matlab, I can use a built it variable `filesep` or `ispc()` or `ismac()` to find out.

Is there a similar function in imageJ?

Thanks

Comment: **You can use `/` as a directory separator character on Windows.** The only thing to watch out for is that paths start with `C:/` instead of just `/`.

Comment: So there isn’t an implementation similar to the one I’m looking for? Or this is the only workaround?

Comment: I don't know - I'm not an imagej user - but what I'm saying is that you don't need any workarounds because `/` will work on Windows.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. Using Fiji, you can use `File.separator`.

See further documentation [here](https://imagej.net/developer/macro/functions.html#file)